# .htaccess allow access for docker proxy container

Tags: apache, .htaccess, docker, nginx

I have 4 containers. Main one with nginx that serves as proxy and redirect all traffic to another 3 containers. Those containers are with apache and stores different web application. Each of this container, contain folder with .htaccess. This file allows access to this folder only for particular IPes. And here is the issue when I remove this file everything work and traffic is redirected but when I add this file as follow:

```
 order allow,deny
 allow from 172.26.0.0/16 (IP of the nginx-proxy)
 allow from nginx-proxy.net (name of the container)
 allow from x.x.x.x (another IPes)
 deny from all
```

It doesn't work and I'm getting 'You don't have permission to acces ...'. How to make it work with .htaccess or maybe there should be different approach. But only particular folder need to be protected the rest no. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this setup, I would:

1. Remove the `.htaccess` files; and
2. Make sure the backend services aren't published with `docker run -p` or Docker Compose `ports:` options.

Docker's standard networking setup gives containers private IP addresses as mostly an implementation detail.  Callers from outside the current host (and in some cases even callers on the same host) can't reach the containers' IP addresses directly; they must contact the host and use a container's published TCP port.  If a container doesn't have a published port, it's not reachable.

Between containers, so long as they're on the same Docker-internal network (or are in the same `docker-compose.yml` file with no explicit `networks:`), they can reach each other directly using the container names as hostnames.

So if you ran:

```
docker network create app
docker run --net app -p 80:80 -v ... nginx
docker run --net app                 service1
docker run --net app                 service2
docker run --net app                 service3
```

Then:

- The nginx container can `proxy_pass http://service1/`, because the services are on the same Docker-internal network
- Off-host callers can reach `http://physical_host.example.com/`, and HTTP port 80 on the host gets routed to the nginx containers
- Off-host callers can't reach the three back-end services except via the nginx proxy

If that's the only control you're trying to implement via Apache's access mechanisms, then Docker's IP-level protection is enough for you here.

Comment: Maybe I was not precious enough. By using .htaccess I want to allow access to my clients IPes but deny to everybody else that want to access /admin folder in my domain. This is necessary to filter their Ipes. So everyone can access my domain but only my clients can access my domain/admin. So the question is how I can do this using .htaccess in docker containers.